# Is it possible to get List<T> without some objects?

Tags: asp.net, linq

Need to get all data from List  without status and date

```
    public class Locations
{
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }

    public string SupplierId { get; set; }

    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public DteTime date{ get; set; }
    public int ResultCode { get; set; }
    public string ResultMessage { get; set; }
}
```

I getting all locations in below list, I want to avoid status and date from the `results`

```
List<Locations> results
```

Comment: What do you mean by you "want to avoid status and date"? If you have a `List<Locations>` then you have `Status` and `date`. What does "avoiding" mean to you in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use `Anonymous Types`

```
results.Select(x=>new{x.CompanyCode,x.SupplierId,x.LocationName,x.ResultCode,x.ResultMessage})
```

Alternatively, you could create a Custom class with only the desired property and project it using Linq as shown in the example with Anonymous Types

Answer (score 0):

or you can use deriving from class/interface and then cast to it ;)

you can do something like this:

```
public interface ILocationsPoorData
{
public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public string SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public int ResultCode { get; set; }
    public string ResultMessage { get; set; }
}



class Locations:ILocationsPoorData
{
public string CompanyCode { get; set; }

    public string SupplierId { get; set; }

    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public DteTime date{ get; set; }
    public int ResultCode { get; set; }
    public string ResultMessage { get; set; }
}
```

and in the end, when you'll have list of locations, you can do sth like this:

```
var newList = locationsList.select(x=> x as ILocationsPoorData)
```

or

```
var newList = locationsList.Cast<ILocationsPoorData>();
```

or you can create class instead of interface and do the same ;)

or you can use anonymous types like in previous answer

or you can create some value tuple instead of anonymous types ;)